# flutter, how to align the cross ICON to center position?

Tags: flutter

```
SizedBox(
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: null,
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
),
```

I want to size Button and also want to put the ICON to center position, but it aligns bottomright little bit... how can I do it? (button size should be 20x20)

my code result picture

[image: my code result picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `Container` instead of `SizedBox` and set `alignment:Alignment.center`, refer [`Align`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html):

```
   Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 20,
            height: 20,
            child: FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: null,
              child: Icon(
                Icons.add,
                size: 15,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Result:

[image]

Other way:

```
     FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: null,
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: thanks! but size of Button should be 20 x 20... Is there any solution without resizing?

Comment: I checked it! Big Thanks to you bro!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add size for icon too:

```
SizedBox(
    width: 20,
    height: 20,
    child: FloatingActionButton(
      onPressed: null,
      child: Icon(
        Icons.add,
        size: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

by default `Icon` size is `24`, so when you want smaller size than that you need to change Icon size too.

[image]

Comment: supercalifragilisticexpialidocious! thx

Comment: @eamirho3ein `SizedBox` not take `alignment` property

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil yes you are right, at first I answer that with container, but change it to SizedBox and forgot to remove the alignment

Answer (score 1):

`FloatingActionButton` has a parameter named as `mini` which is `false` default and can be used. Someone might be interested on it.

```dart
FloatingActionButton(
  onPressed: null,
  mini: true,
  child: Icon(Icons.add),
),
```

Left one is using `mini:true`

[image]

Comment: Also check `materialTapTargetSize` if needed